# JAXB Not able to get the the Object from XML

Tags: jaxb

While running the java file for converting XML to Java class object it is giving this output instead of the XML file

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class XMLToObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {

        File file = new File("file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(customer);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
}
```

Output :
Customer@2c2c14f9

Please Help me in getting the XML file output in Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all I found the solution. It was silly a mistake. I need to call the public getter methods of the class to access the real data... Thank you for help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently seeing the result of calling `toString()` on your instance of `Customer`.  You need to use a `Marshaller` to output the object to XML.

```
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
```

Comment: But have the XML file then what is the need to marshal it again? It is already marshaled. And I need the Customer Object to be printed like toString() method of it.. Not the XML file.. I have XML file... And i need to convert it to Object sothat i can use it in my java code.. Thanks for the reply but i need something different.